Multi-hop access keeps asking for password on second machine
In my company, for many reasons, we need to use the company's machines to compile and run our application. I've been using Emacs+Tramp for a while to access my machine and it works very well most of the time.
Since our machines are only visible in the company's internal network, I have access to a VPN so I can directly connect to my remote work machine. This means I can access my machine with a single hop, and my password is asked only once.
Every once in a while, though, the VPN goes down and I have to hop first into an ssh server exposed to the internet, then hop into my machine. This works fine with Tramp, but one major inconvenience is that the password for the second machine keeps being asked for no clear reason. Most notably:

Whenever I recompile my code, Tramp will ask for the password
I have eglot enabled, so whenever eglot initializes (e.g. I'm opening a file for the first time), Tramp will ask for the password twice

This gets old really quickly. How can I solve it?

Have you tried using built in ~/.authinfo.gpg configuration file for password caching? You will be prompted once for password to decrypt gpg file and emacs will fetch other passwords from encrypted file. Then you can configure how long emacs will keep cached passwords in memory to prevent additional prompts until you restart emacs and gpg agent.

Where can I find info on that?

This section of TRAMP manual is what I was referring too. Hope that helps!

Thanks! I noticed I do have the authinfo file, but it only seems to work for the outer machine. I adjusted the auth-source-save-behavior to ask, but it never asks me to save the password for the inner machine.

This still keeps happening. What I noticed is that the ~/.authinfo.gpg file only seems to have any effect at all to first-hop connections. Maybe this is a known limitation of emacs?

Not sure if this will help but I noticed that processes in which a tty was allocated instead of a pipe had more luck with authinfo because emacs was able to answer or recognize the password prompt because of the tty. Perhaps forcing the remote process to allocate a tty might help?

How do I force the remote process to allocate a tty?

Good question not sure with TRAMP. It might be available under Customize for TRAMP or perhaps in manual. This may be a wild goose chase.

It was a bug, apparently. By pure coincidence, I sent the same question1 to the official support mailing list and, by pure coincidence, one of Emacs's devs rewrote Tramp's password handling code a few days prior to fix a different bug2. This new code happened to also fix my problem.
The fix will land on Emacs 30.2 and also Tramp 2.7.1.5, which should be released later this month.3

Cool!! Thanks for asking your question!!
